# Segfault on Copy Constructor of LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm writing a class that will serve as a container for a singly-linked list for Student objects (a custom class, the specification of which is irrelevant). It is perfectly functional (I can add and remove Nodes easily), with the exception of the copy constructor. With my copy constructor, I aim to copy only the data of the list (i.e. not the pointers themselves), but it segfaults for some reason.

Below is the relevant code (Annotated with comments to explain ambiguous parts):

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& copy) {
    Student s = copy.head->getStudent();
    //Node can be initialized with a Student pointer argument
    head = new Node(new Student(s.getFirstName(), s.getMiddleInitial(),s.getLastName(),s.getSSN(),s.getAge()));
    Node *curr = copy.head->getNext();
    Node* prev = head; //For saving the tail
    while(curr != NULL){
        Student s = curr->getStudent();
        append(s);
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }
    tail = prev;
    cout << "Leaving method..." << endl;
}


//Irrelevant methods omitted
void LinkedList::append(Node*& n) {
    cout << "Got to appending to node obj" << endl;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail = n;
     } else {
        tail->setNext(n);
        tail = tail->getNext();
    }
}

void LinkedList::append(Student s) {
    Node* n = new Node(s.getFirstName(),s.getMiddleInitial(),s.getLastName(),s.getSSN(),s.getAge());
    append(n);
}
//From Node.cpp
void Node::setNext(Node*  _next) {
    next = _next; //Next is a Node pointer (i.e. Node*)
}
```

I'd like to emphasize that this code works fine when adding to the original list. It is only during the copy constructor that this code fails. I ran this code through Valgrind and I get the following error:

```
==23990== Invalid write of size 8
==23990==    at 0x403018: Node::setNext(Node*) (Node.cpp:86)  //This is the "next = _next" line
==23990==    by 0x402694: LinkedList::append(Node*&) (LinkedList.cpp:81)   
==23990==    by 0x402371: LinkedList::append(Student) (LinkedList.cpp:90)
==23990==    by 0x401F68: LinkedList::LinkedList(LinkedList const&) (LinkedList.cpp:31)
```

This confuses me as the pointer is (and should be) of size 8, being saved to a pointer (which is size 8).

What exactly is the cause of the segfault? Why does this code fail during the copy constructor but not when being called otherwise?

Comment: It's not the size of the write that's invalid, but rather a write (of size 8) that's invalid. It looks like `tail` may be invalid (which is the object that you pass to `append`) -- are you sure it's properly initialized?

Comment: You are missing much of the relevant code. Take a look at [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Cameron Can you explain what would cause the write to be invalid? Even if only in the general case.

Comment: @Deduplicator Can you elaborate on what is missing? I don't think this is a problem I can reduce to a toy example.

Comment: @ahjohnston25: Well, any write to an invalid address (e.g. reserved regions, 0, etc.), or an address that the program does not own is invalid. There's likely a null or uninitialized variable somewhere.

Comment: The definition of `LinkedList`, especially members, ctors and dtor.

Comment: And the ctor of `Node` would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over complicating it you can just do it in the while loop:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& copy) {
  Student s = copy.head->getStudent();
//Node can be initialized with a Student pointer argument
  head = new Node(new Student(s.getFirstName(),s.getMiddleInitial(),s.getLastName(),s.getSSN(),s.getAge()));
  Node *curr = copy.head->getNext();
  Node *newListCur = head;
  Node* prev = head; //For saving the tail
  while(curr != NULL){
    Student s = curr->getStudent();
   //important step
    Node* newNode = new Node(new Student(s.getFirstName(),s.getMiddleInitial(),s.getLastName(),s.getSSN(),s.getAge()));
    newListCur->setNext(newNode);
   //
    newListCur = newListCur->getNext();
    curr= curr->getNext();
  }
  cout << "Leaving method..." << endl;
}
```

This does not check for NULL heads though so you might have to add that logic

Comment: Thank you. This runs without segfaulting.